# Upload with angularjs and rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, upload

I want to upload an illustrations image with my post, i have installed carrierwwave and angularjs-file-upload but it's not work

```
%form.edit-user{:role => "form", :multipart => "true"}
    [..another field of my post..]
%input{:type => "file", :name => "image", "nv-file-select"=>"", "uploader"=>"uploader"}
```

I've write this code my form, into my carrierwave class :

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
end
```

My model :

```
class Recette < ActiveRecord::Base
   mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

and my controller :

```
def create
    @recette = Recette.new(params.require(:recette).permit(:name,:instructions))
    @recette.image = params[:image]
    @recette.save
    render 'show', status: 201
  end
```

i've loaded the module into my app angular and add this into my controller :

```
$scope.uploader = new FileUploader({url: '/recettes/new'}, {alias: 'image'});
```

I use jbuilder gem and my _recette.json.jbuilder :

```
json.(recette, :id, :name, :instructions, :image)
```

Thanks you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this :

```
$scope.uploader = new FileUploader({url: '/recettes/new'}, {alias: 'image', formData: 'Your Data'});
```

You need to specify in 'formData' object all your data will be send with your upload.

[Refer to documentation](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/wiki/Module-API)

Comment: Please explain how this line of code works to resolve the question.